# How to verify that $P \in \langle Q_1, \dots, Q_m \rangle$ in $\mathbb C[x_1, \dots , x_n]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

For $P, Q_1, \dots, Q_m \in \mathbb C[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, how to verify that
$$P \in \langle Q_1, \dots, Q_m \rangle?$$

What are known algorithms to write $P$ as a combination of the $Q_1, \dots, Q_m$?

What if we replace $\mathbb C$ with another field?

My question comes from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009454/kernel-of-the-homomorphism-mathbb-cx-y-z-%E2%86%92-mathbb-ct-de%EF%AC%81ned-by-x%E2%86%92t-y%E2%86%92-t#2009478).

Comment: I believe that Groebner bases give you a way to determine this algorithmically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Buchberger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm) for finding a [Gröbner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis).